# publish multiple projects from VisualStudio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment

I have a solution with several web applications projects.
How can I publish all of them at once?
In VisualStudio 2010, the solution doesn't have an option to do that.

I found out this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404233.aspx

Note that I do NOT use ClickOnce, I am trying to do the publish to a directory(for now).

Running the macro gives an error:

> An exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException' occurred in
>   VBAssembly but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Not implemented (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80004001 (E_NOTIMPL))

I can't understand why it cannot call Save() on the project object, since it is the project.

Thanks!
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue with VS2012. You have to make publish profiles for every project. Maybe this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13647129/vs2012-publish-multiple-projects-in-a-solution) helps.