# VS2012 publish multiple projects in a solution

Tags: visual-studio-2012, publish

We are using VS2012. We have a solution with mulitple web projects and are using publish to deploy a project. There are already quite a few projects in the solution. To publish all of them at once it is pretty time consuming. Is there a way to publish all the projects at once?

Comment: On a bit of a sidenote: there's a tool called octopus deploy that might be of interest if you're deploying this many projects to IIS.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found out I can use msbuild at the command line to publish multiple projects.

```
msbuild example.sln /p:Configuration=Test;DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=Test.example.pubxml /MaxCpuCount:8
```

Comment: @StefanHa I am also searching to the similar solution the only difference I need is to publish selected project in the solution and put one published project as a folder in other published web project. Do you have any idea for this?

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in publishing from command line:

```
msbuild YourSolution.sln /property:Configuration=Release;DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=Production
```

You can find further reading on [Scott Hanselman's blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TinyHappyFeatures3PublishingImprovementsChainedConfigTransformsAndDeployingASPNETAppsFromTheCommandLine.aspx) for example.