# msbuild DeployOnBuild=true argument not working

Tags: visual-studio-2012, deployment, msbuild, publish

I am trying to automatically publish all the projects of my .NET solution using the DeplyOnBuild=true argument (according to this  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13647129/vs2012-publish-multiple-projects-in-a-solution) )

I typed this command in the PowerShell:

> msbuild mysolultion.sln /p:Configuration=Debug;DeployOnBuild=true;

But I get the following error message :

> The term 'DeployOnBuild=true' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>   At line:1 char:59
>   + msbuild mysolution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug;DeployOnBuild=true <<<< ;
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (DeployOnBuild=true:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerShell is interpreting everything after your first semicolon as a separate command.

You need to use quotes:

`MSBuild example.sln /p:"Configuration=Debug;DeployOnBuild=true;"`

Or use separate `/p` parameters:

`MSBuild example.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:DeployOnBuild=true`