# VS2015 publish multiple web project in a solution on build

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have solution which has three web projects(Site1, Site2 and Web.Shared).

[image]

I have defined Publish Profile for all the three projects. I have to publish each project for deploying changes to deploy folder.

I tried [VS2012 publish multiple projects in a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13647129/vs2012-publish-multiple-projects-in-a-solution) and https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/09/22/web-publish-how-to-automate-multi-project-publish-with-file-system/. That did not help.

Is there a way for publishing all the three projects during build?

Answer (score 0):

You may use PowerShell to run MSBuild using the following command:

```
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\msbuild.exe" SolutionXXXX.sln /p:Configuration=Release /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=PublishRelease /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0 /MaxCpuCount:8
```

I tested this using Visual Studio 2017.